# Validation failed, I cannot find the cause of the error though

Tags: html, validation, error-handling

Good day,

I have tried to validate my HTML page a few times over the last few weeks and every time this on error come up which is quite annoying as I cannot find anything wrong with that section of code in terms of element tags not being closed etc.
It is telling me that there is no opening paragraph tag in the paragraph. However I can confidently say there is...

### The error (according to [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)):

> Validation Output: 1 Error
>
> Error Line 18, Column 618: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

```
…="Not Very Popular Name"><strong><q>Name</q></strong></abbr>
> Name</p**>**
```

### The code section before and including the location of the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Living life on the Brink</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about-me.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="about-me">
<hr>
<h1>My Name</h1>
<p>I dont normally like talking about myself, so I'll try and express myself and who I am mostly with images, although I am supposed to use the full range of HTML elements which we have learned in week 1 <br>:)</p>
</header>
<div class="location">
<hr>
<h2>Location, location, location...</h2>
<p>I like to think I have an open outlook to things. Having gone from my <em>birthplace</em> in <blockquote><strong>A place</strong><sub>English</sub></blockquote> to my <em>home</em> in <blockquote><strong>A place</strong> <sup>German</sup></blockquote> through my recent <em>educational paradise</em> in <blockquote><strong>A place</strong><sub>Spanish</sub></blockquote> into <blockquote><strong>A place</strong><sup>English <sup>AGAIN</sup></sup></blockquote> all the way to where I stand right now, Another place... <abbr title="Not Very Popular Name"><strong><q>Name</q></strong></abbr> Name.</p>
```

So what could the problem be? Could someone point out the error which is most probably an extremely obvious error which escapes me... Is it possible that there are too many elements nested within the paragraph element? It shouldn't be but could it be a possibility?

Thank you!
Saborknight

Answer (score 1):

`<blockquote>` is a block-level element, not allowed inside `<p>` tag ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements